# Playing MP3 in Firefox on Debian

Tags: debian, firefox, crunchbang, mp3, bunsenlabs

Is there a way to get MP3 playback within Firefox 31+ without installing plugins? I know about the entire encoding issues, but I have read somewhere that Firefox will look for native OS encoders like LAME to add support for audio HTML5 tags.

What is the best way to add MP3 support for Firefox 31+ on Debian 7/Bunselabs?

Comment: Iceweasel (Debian's version of Firefox) should support that out of the box (it does for me). If it doesn't, please provide an example URL of something that doesn't play?

Answer (score 3):

from [Enabling HTML5 MP3 Playback in Firefox 30 and Above](https://linuxtechie.wordpress.com/2014/08/05/enabling-html5-mp3-playback-in-firefox-30-and-above-3/), firefox 30+ is now using gstreamer1.0, and you need the mp3-capable plugins for it.

```
apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

And restart firefox

Comment: AFAIK mp3 specifically is in the "ugly" category. Not sure if you really need to install the "bad" one.